# Query on how to select data based on single condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need your help to review the below request.

i am using the below query and what i want to achieve is as below

i am trying to extract the min value of the new_status_id and not fetch any other details of any other status at all. Basically i am getting more than one line as output for one v_id that i input where as the desired output is one line and min(timestamp) to get fetched under column name Upload as defined below

```
Select
to_char(to_date(date,'DY Mon DD YYYY'),'MM-DD')||' '||Away_team.name||' '||'@'||' '||home_team.name as "Title",
video_jobs.id as "Job Id",
markets.name as "Market",
round as "Round",
to_char(to_date(date,'DY Mon DD YYYY'),'DD-Mon-YY') as "Date Aired",
competitions.name as "Competition",
Home_team.name as "Home Team",
Away_team.name as "Away Team",
job_statuses.name as "Job Status",
networks.name as "Network",
stadiums.name as "Stadium",
Round(images_count/3600.0,2) as "Footage Hours",
round(sum(minutes_in_logo_finder)/60.0,2) as "Logo Picker Time",
Round(sum(minutes_in_hits_editor)/60.0,2) as "Hits Editing Time",
Round(sum(minutes_in_branding)/60.0,2) as "Branding Time",
Round(sum(minutes_in_tagging)/60.0,2) as "Tagging Time",
Round(sum(minutes_in_qc)/60.0,2)as "QC Time",
Round(sum(minutes_in_idle)/60.0,2) as "Idle Time",
Round(sum(loading_time)/60.0,2) as "Loading Time",
Round(sum(minutes_in_logo_finder+minutes_in_hits_editor + minutes_in_branding +minutes_in_tagging +minutes_in_qc+minutes_in_idle+loading_time)/60.0,2) as "Total"

from video_jobs 
Join markets on video_jobs.market_id = markets.id
Join stadiums on video_jobs.stadium_id = Stadiums.id
Join job_statuses on video_jobs.status_id = job_statuses.id
Join competitions on video_jobs.competition_id = competitions.id
Join networks on video_jobs.network_id = networks.id
Join sessions on video_jobs.id = sessions.job_id
join teams as Home_team on video_jobs.home_team_id = home_team.id
join teams as Away_team on video_jobs.away_team_id = Away_team.id
Join video_job_status_history on video_jobs.id = video_job_status_history.video_job_id

Where video_jobs.id > 163026  

group by
video_jobs.id,
markets.name,
video_jobs.round,
stadiums.name,
job_statuses.name,
competitions.name,
networks.name,
video_jobs.images_count,
home_team.name,
Away_team.name,
video_jobs.date

order by 
video_jobs.id
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data of your table and the result you're expecting to get?

Comment: So you want to retrieve *one row*, not just one column? The row with the minimum timestamp? Please match your question / explanation to the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the condition into the `where` clause:

```
select min(timestamp) as "Uplaod"
from v_jobs
where v_id = 1234 and new_status_id = 25;
```

EDIT:

In that case, what you want is conditional aggregation:

```
select min(case when new_status_id = 25 then timestamp end) as MinTimestamp25
. . .
```

Comment: thanks, the other supporting info is that i am using other where condition as well. sorry missed to say that.. this is only part of the code that i have published above.. let me know if you need the full code to guide me through..

Comment: Hi Gordon,The query also has selects id's which do not have the status id against them. any help..

Comment: @user3139623 . . . If `new_status_id` is `NULL` on all the rows for a given group, then the expression will return `NULL`.